# Why is array.map(String.fromCharCode) so slow?

Tags: javascript, optimization

It started out when I read Guido van Rossum's essay [An Optimization Anecdote](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str.html).

Deciding to try the same thing in JavaScript, I timed the following:

```
numbers.map(function(x){ return String.fromCharCode(x); });
```

This was pretty fast already, but why not eliminate the anonymous function completely and pass String.fromCharCode directly to map():

```
numbers.map(String.fromCharCode);
```

I timed it and... ...**this was ~100 times slower** than the previous version. How come?

Somehow passing this native function directly to Array.map() is way slower than wrapping it inside another function and passing that to Array.map().

- It's not browser specific: tested in Chrome, Firefox and Opera.
- It's not specific to map(): tried forEach(), which behaved similarly.
- It's not specific to built-in functions: tried Math.round() and Math.sin() - with these the results were as one would expect: passing the function to Array.map() directly was a little bit faster than using intermediate anonymous function.

It seems the problem is with String.fromCharCode specifically.

What's going on here?

PS. Originally posed this question in [Hacker News thread](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1859417), but since the related article is about Python, I thought it would get more exposure to JavaScript devs when posted here. Sorry for cross-posting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution by myself.

The problem is that String.fromCharCode() takes multiple arguments and Array.map() also passes multiple arguments to the callback. Therefore the code:

```
numbers.map(String.fromCharCode);
```

Is actually equivalent of:

```
numbers.map(function(x, y, z){ return String.fromCharCode(x, y, z); });
```

From which it is quite apparent why it's so slow. Additionally it's buggy too.

Comment: I was just about to post this same answer.  The expected result is different because `String.fromCharCode` constructs the returned string from all arguments passed in (in this case, the first 2 arguments passed in because the third isn't a number).